# RecyclerView не отображает кастомные View

Tags: android, recyclerview

Возникла проблема с `RecyclerView`, не могу найти решение в гугле. Есть фрагмент, внутри `RecyclerView`. Элементы генерятся, но не отображаются.

> Класс фрагмента - https://github.com/LazyTechwork/QRScanner/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/lazytechwork/qrscanner/fragments/HistoryFragment.kt

```
class HistoryFragment : Fragment() {
    private var scans: List<Scan> = emptyList()
    private val ioScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewAdapter: ScanHistoryAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false)

        viewAdapter = ScanHistoryAdapter(scans, (activity as MainActivity).db)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.scanlist).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = viewAdapter
        }

        ioScope.launch {
            scans = (activity as MainActivity).getScans()
            viewAdapter.updateDataset(scans)
        }
        return view
    }

}
```

> XML фрагмента - https://github.com/LazyTechwork/QRScanner/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_history.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/scanlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/history_item" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Код адаптера - https://github.com/LazyTechwork/QRScanner/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/lazytechwork/qrscanner/data/adapters/ScanHistoryAdapter.kt

```
class ScanHistoryAdapter(private var dataset: List<Scan>, private val db: AppDatabase) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ScanHistoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(val historyItem: HistoryItem) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(historyItem)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder =
        ViewHolder(HistoryItem(parent, db))


    fun updateDataset(scans: List<Scan>) {
        dataset = scans
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataset.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val viewItem = holder.historyItem
        val scan = dataset[position]
        viewItem.setScan(scan)
    }
}
```

В Android Studio всё нормально отображается.

[image: Скрин приложения с Android] [image: Android Studio скрин]

Comment: Вставьте, пожалуйста, код в вопрос, по ссылкам неудобно лазить. И картинки бы уменьшить как-то, слишком большие, отвлекают)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Картинки не знаю как уменьшить, могу просто в конец поставить, код сейчас вставлю

Comment: Картинки уменьшать надо до выгрузки. Взять эти же скрины и их уменьшить на компе у себя, а потом сюда выкладывать) Но, думаю, и так как сейчас сойдет) Код адаптера еще выложите, пожалуйста)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Код адаптера и ссылка добавлены

Comment: а как можно в бд данные имея приложение добавить?

Comment: Проверил дебаггером, метод getScans() ничего не возвращает. https://ibb.co/n6JndDB

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Раньше добавлял на каждое событие клика в нижнем навбаре, в MainActivity остался закомментированный код

Comment: @Circassian В бд ничего нет, вот поэтому и 0

Comment: @LazyTechwork и я о том же)

Comment: @Circassian у меня то в бд есть объекты

Comment: Если данные есть, то прилка падает. Так как обновлять адаптер нужно в UI треде)

Comment: @Circassian у меня не падает, не знаю почему. Возможно в этом и ошибка, сейчас посмотрю. Но у меня вот данные есть. https://ibb.co/8NqpYH6

Comment: @Circassian Попробовал запустить через main, всё равно не получилось https://ibb.co/hdTs0f2

Comment: @LazyTechwork Вы в принципе неправильно подошли к задаче. Кастомные view не должны иметь конструкторов отличных от тех, которые есть у их родителей. Их система создает, как она БД в Ваш конструктор добавит?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Возможно и так, но я не понимаю как по-другому передать кастомному View данные. Ладно бд, как нибудь по-другому сделаю, но как кастомному View данные передать? P.S. Передача бд была сделана для того, чтобы на вызов кнопки в кастомном View происходили действия в БД

Comment: @LazyTechwork `viewItem.setScan(scan)` - это Вам чем не передача данных? сами же написали!

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Ну смотрите, мне проще и, я думаю, правильней передать данные сразу на инициализации объекта, чем отправлять их отдельным методом?

Comment: @LazyTechwork в случае с андроидом - нет, Ваш способ неправильный. Объект Вы инициализировать не будете, это система будет делать. Для назначения данных Вы и используете адаптер, он изначально только для этого придумывался)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот тебе новый адаптер. Проверил, все работает

```
class ScanHistoryAdapter2(val db: AppDatabase) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ScanHistoryAdapter2.ScanViewHolder>() {

    var items: List<Scan> = arrayListOf()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = 
        ScanViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.history_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ScanViewHolder, position: Int) =
        holder.bind(position)

    override fun getItemCount() =
        items.size

    inner class ScanViewHolder(
        view: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        fun bind(positon: Int) {
            val scan = items[positon]
            with(itemView) {
                history_name.text = scan.name
                history_date.text = MainActivity.DATE_FORMAT.format(scan.date)
                history_data.text = scan.data
                history_type.setImageResource(
                    when (scan.type) {
                        HistoryType.LINK -> R.drawable.ic_link_outline
                        HistoryType.TEXT -> R.drawable.ic_text_outline
                        HistoryType.CONTACT -> R.drawable.ic_contact_outline
                    }
                )
                favourite_switch.apply {
                    isChecked = scan.isFavourite
                    setOnCheckedChangeListener(FavouriteSwitcher2(db, scan))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class FavouriteSwitcher2(private val db: AppDatabase, private val scan: Scan) :
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private val ioScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
        ioScope.launch {
            if (isChecked)
                db.scansInterface().makeFavourite(scan)
            else
                db.scansInterface().removeFavourite(scan)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Но мой совет, работу с бд вынеси из адаптера. Взаимодействие с адаптером сделай через интерфейс

Comment: И еще, у лэйаута поменяй `layout_height` с `match_parent` на `wrap_content`

Comment: Дай знать, как заимплементишь код

Comment: Да, я уже опробовал, но не пойму почему оно работает, сейчас разбираюсь в чём была проблема. Большое спасибо, теперь буду знать Android чуточку лучше.

Comment: Рад был помочь)

Comment: Можно как-то с тобой связаться, для дальнейшей поддержки?) Telegram/VK